# Javascript code is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the color of `.nav` to the css used in `.past-main` when  I scroll past `#main` but, for some reason the javascript isn't working when I open up the file in my browser. There are no syntax errors or any indication that there is something wrong with my code. So i don't know what else to do. Here is my code:

Html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mooss.css">

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="nav">
        <a href="#" class="logo">[logo]</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="main">#main</div>
    <div id="below-main">#below-main</div>

    <script>
        // get the value of the bottom of the #main element by adding the offset of that element plus its height, set it as a variable

        $(document).ready(function() {

            var mainbottom = $('#main').offset().top + $('#main').height();

            // on scroll, 
            $(window).on('scroll', function() {

                // we round here to reduce a little workload
                stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());

                if (stop > mainbottom) {
                    $('.nav').addClass('past-main');
                } else {
                    $('.nav').removeClass('past-main');
                }

            });

        })
    </script>

</body>
```

And here is the css:

```
.nav {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 1em 0;
         /* make sure to add vendor prefixes here */;
}

.nav.past-main {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #444;
}

#main {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}

#below-main {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Add `console.log(stop + ' : ' + mainbottom);` after you define stop and then look at the console to see what the numbers are doing. Maybe not doing what you think.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Here's a fiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/vunhpaoh/  You just want the logo header to turn white as they scroll past the main section, correct?

Comment: Yes that is what I want

Comment: But for some reason it isn't working when I open it up in my browser

Comment: Works fine for me also.  Are you including jQuery somewhwhere?  I don't see it in your code

Comment: All I did was copy and paste your code. Perhaps your browser has cached the page or you are missing a file include (e.g., jQuery).

Comment: Is that really your whole HTML file? I don't see an HTML deceleration. And missing jquery.

Comment: have you included jquery??? I mean jquery.js or jquery.min.js?

Comment: No i haven't, could you tell me how i would do that please

Comment: I've answered how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything's fine. You should add jquery.min.js like this,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That is the only thing missing as per your reply to my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `class="nav"` and accessing it via `nav`, not `.nav`

```js
// get the value of the bottom of the #main element by adding the offset of that element plus its height, set it as a variable

$(document).ready(function() {

    var mainbottom = $('#main').offset().top + $('#main').height();

// on scroll, 
$(window).on('scroll',function(){

    // we round here to reduce a little workload
    stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());

if (stop > mainbottom) {
        $('nav').addClass('past-main');
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('past-main');
   }

});

})
```

```css
 nav {
background-color:transparent;
color:#fff;
transition: all 0.25s ease;
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
background-color:#ccc;
padding:1em 0;
/* make sure to add vendor prefixes here */
 }

  nav.past-main {
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#444;
  }

  #main {
   height:500px;
   background-color:red;
  }

 #below-main {
  height:1000px;
  background-color:#eee;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="logo">[logo]</a>
</nav>
<div id="main">#main</div>
<div id="below-main">#below-main</div>

</body>
```